# Error: Cannot redeclare class becuase of entity self reference

Tags: 8

I've got 2 problems here.

I have an entity that references itself in field definition (see below).

Problem No.1. I've got a fatal error 
`PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Drupal\mymodule\MyEntity` when trying to install the module.

Problem No.2 I now get it every time even when I remove the referencing field and do `drush cr` unless I wrap the class definition in `!class_exists()`.

I swear this is the only file defining the class.

Is there a way to clean this out of wherever drupal has stored it?

And how do I declare this type of self-reference?

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition;

/**
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *     id = "myentity",
 *     label = "My Entity",
 *     base_table = "myentity"
 * )
 */
class MyEntity extends ContentEntityBase
{
    public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type)
    {
        $fields = [];

        // Standard field, used as unique if primary index.
        $fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
            ->setLabel(t('ID'))
            ->setReadOnly(true);

        $fields['myentity_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
            ->setTargetEntityTypeId('myentity');

        $fields['name'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string');

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's funny, but even renaming entity and class doesn't help. It will still say `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Drupal\mymodule\MyEntityz`

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the problem was in the namespace:

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule;
```

From my observation (can't find this in the [Entity API documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/group/entity_api/8.1.x) entities are supposed to be placed in the src/Entity (which I did) which imposes the `Entity` namespace. So fixing the namespace solved my issue.

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Entity;
```

What a stupid way to spend a half of a day. Looks like I'm too used to class loaders that will simply not find the class if you place it in the wrong directory.

Comment: Drupal's class loader does not find it if you put it in the wrong directory. But that's not what you did. You put it in the right directory, with the wrong namespace. Which means that the class loader finds the file, includes it, but the expected class still doesn't exist yet. Then there is another attempt at loading it and it fails because the file class defined it in already exists. No class loader can prevent you from that.

Comment: 1. Right directory for the `Drupal\mymodule\MyEntity` class is 
`{module_dir}/` and `{module_dir}/Entity/` is wrong directory. So loading `Drupal\mymodule\MyEntity` from `{module_dir}/Entity/MyEntity.php` is also wrong and should not happen, let alone twice...

Comment: Entity types are found based on annotation discovery, which is file based, then the class name is derived from that. So yes, if Drupal would look for `Drupal\mymodule\MyEntity`, it would simplfy fail and not find it, but it doesn't do that, it looks for `Drupal\mymodule\Entity\MyEntity`, finds your file for it but the class name there is not as expected. The only way to detect that would be to do a class exists check after loading the file, Drupal uses standard composer class loading, so you'd have to open an issue there to do that.

Comment: Sorry, why would I open an issue with composer for something that "Drupal doesn't do that"? When using composer autoloader the right way there is no such problem - you reference a class, composer loads the file, and if there was wrong class in the file PHP fails with 'Unknown class'.

Comment: I don't know why Drupal does it the way it does, but that's a major problem with Drupal - you get either no error message whatsoever or an error message that's completely useless, like this `The 'set' plugin does not exist`. Obviously this does not give any clue to what type of plugin it's talking about, where is it supposed to be placed, what class name, nothing that can help the developer resolve it.